# Dynamically changing a HTML DB via a third party user-friendly app?

Tags: html, database, cordova, twitter

I'm having trouble finding a way to make my HTML-based app (PhoneGap), to make it so that the information displayed can be changed via a third-party app, to explain this further let's say that I'm displaying a product with a price, and it shows via a list an image, title and the price. now the client and owner, wants to change the image, but he doesn't know how to use a DB or how to change the app.

what I've been thinking as an example to use twitter on a private account so that when the user uploads an image with especified hashtags, the product app can read from there and update. now because I'm using phoneGap there isn't really a page uploaded to a server so I can register for twitters API.

so I'm kinda lost, so I was hoping if anyone here could point me in the right direction so that I can research.

Thanks.

Comment: why don't you provide him a Form where he can load the image and the product details. This will be stored in the DB and the App will fetch the data from the stored location. This has to be managed at the backend.. I am not able to understand, it should be quite simple, Am I missing something.?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that is pretty simple actually, but I'm trying to find a way so that the client doesn't need to contact me to update the information, and also not to maintain a Database(server). (I don't know if I explained myself correctly).

Comment: The backend need not be a Database. It can be stored on the file system of the server.